# ssh: login in LAN works, WAN using ngrokh fails

Tags: linux, ssh, router, lan

Over the LAN I can ssh from my laptop to my RPi without any problems using my public key.

The debug output from ssh in the successfull case:

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: moritz@my_hostname
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
```

If I try to use ngrok over the WAN, I get following output:

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: moritz@my_hostname
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/moritz/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/moritz/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/moritz/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/moritz/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

In both cases i do `ssh pi-user@ip-adress` and the file `/home/pi-user/.ssh/authorized_keys` is given in the correct form within the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file

On the server, I use the ngrok/ARM version and started it with `ngrok 22`
I connected the service ssh and https in my router configuration with the Raspberry.

Any ideas why ?

In the meantime I found this answer:

> `sudo chmod -c g-w /home/lorddaedra` 
>   fixed my problem. So need change 775 to 755 on user home directory. If > anyone know reason why 775 is bad please comment..
>
> I do not have enough reputation to comment, so this goes in a separate answer. The reason that you had to change the permissions to 755 is that you have StrictMode set to yes, which means: StrictModes yes The option StrictModes specifies whether ssh should check user's permissions in their home directory and rhosts files before accepting login.

from this post [link to servefault_SO](https://serverfault.com/questions/230771/ssh-configuration-publickeys-permission-denied-publickey-password-error)

I am not at home, but will try it next week.

Comment: show us your tunnel (ngrok).

Comment: you mean the log files ?

Comment: well, as I understand your description, you are using Ngrok as a reverse tunnel, so you can connect to your local ssh service from outside your network. but the ssh command you have shown us is no different from one you would use if ngrok was not in play, so there is no guarranty that your ngrok config is working or that its used at all in your LAN case. show us what you have done to establish the ngrok tunnel, on the ssh host, and how you are connecting to the ngrok service to access the tunnel when your laptop is outside the LAN.